# What's the term for claiming someone does something that you do to weaken the power of people's criticism of you doing it?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example if a politician who's corrupt accuses another one of being corrupt with the intention of making it less likely for people to believe accusations against their corruption.

I don't really mean projection, I think that's more subconscious.

Comment: Hypernyms are _pre-emptive strike_ (if the timescale fits), _diversionary tactic_ and, of course, _hypocrisy / the pot calling the kettle black_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common tactic used by corrupt leaders, isn't it, from Trump* to Mugabe.  It's akin to the phrase "The pot calling the kettle black", but that doesn't feel "strong" enough, or formal enough.

It's an example of a **[rhetorical device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_device)**, but I don't think it has a proper name.  There's a quote which is often wrongly attributed to Josef Goebbels, "accuse the other side of that which you are guilty".  He was a master of propaganda so it's understandable that people might think he said it, but there's no evidence that he ever did.  He did say that Germany's enemies were employing that technique against Germany, though.

I don't think **projection** is quite right as that implies that the speaker thinks that the opponent really is guilty, whereas you're talking about a deliberate lie.

You could say "Blame shifting" but that tends to be more used to put the blame on someone else on your own side, like "scapegoating".

It's described on [this page](http://variable-variability.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/karl-rove-strategy-weakness-of-mitigation-sceptics.html) as the **Karl Rove Strategy #3**, named after the US Republican political strategist.  So, this name is obviously very politicised, unless Mr Rove is happy to be credited with it, which I doubt.

*if anyone is strongly offended by this reference to Trump then I'm happy to replace it with another less controversial reference.  I certainly don't want to turn this  into a political argument.  He did accuse Hilary of several things of which he was guilty and she wasn't, though, during the campaign.